# Debugging create react app in vscode with attach configurations

Tags: visual-studio-code, create-react-app, vscode-debugger

I want to debug my react app in VSCode, Setting up a launch.json with chrome "launch" configuration is easy and working, but if I set up the launch.json with "attach" configuration it won't work.

```
"configurations": [
{
  "name": "Attach to Chrome",
  "port": 9222,
  "request": "attach",
  "type": "pwa-chrome",
  "urlFilter": "http://localhost:3000/*",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

]

I have already added this: `--remote-debugging-port=9222 -- "%1"` to my chrome properties and yet I still get an error from vscode that there is no debuggable target found on that port.

I just want to debug my app without re-launching a new chrome and or losing my states or progress in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct launch config. You have to first close all instances of chrome to it gets launched again by the vscode.

Note: userDataDir lets you use your existing profiles in chrome.

```
       {
            "name": "Launch Chrome for Debugging",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "chrome",
            "url": "https://localhost:3000/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            "userDataDir": false
        },
```